# WPML : how to determine manually the language in which a given page is displayed

Tags: plugin-wpml

Somewhere in my code I need to know what is the current language and display a certain custom field or another one based on this knowledge.

How can I know this information ?

Comment: http://wpml.org/documentation/

Comment: Yes it was there : http://wpml.org/documentation/support/wpml-coding-api/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WPML defines constants that you can use go get the current language:

- `ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE` - current language code (eg: en,fr,sp).
- `ICL_LANGUAGE_NAME_EN` - Name of the current language in English (eg: English, French. Spanish).
- `ICL_LANGUAGE_NAME` - Name of current language, in the current language (eg: English, Français, Español).